# Why key and main window not be the top window?

Tags: macos, nswindow

osx- I have two windows, 
I initially set the first window be key window, 
then set the second window to be key window, 
then I call [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:Yes].
And I print [[NSApplication sharedApplication] orderedWindows];

I found, if the first window closed, the orderedWindows will be only the second Window.

But if the first window is still open, even if I had made the second window be key and main, but the orderedWindows will be {firstWindow, secondWindow}

But I want the second window be the front the one.

I also make the secondWindow do like this:

```
  [captureWindow setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel + 2];
  [captureWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
  [captureWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
  [captureWindow setMovableByWindowBackground:NO];
  [captureWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
  [captureWindow orderFrontRegardless];
  [captureWindow orderFront:self];
  [captureWindow makeKeyWindow];
  [captureWindow makeMainWindow];
  [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

But when [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]; once executed, if the first window is still on screen, then the windowOrdered will be {firstWindow, secondWindow}, so I thinks the orderFront is not worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither "key" nor "main" is related to ordering. If you want to make a window ordered front, then the method is `[NSWindow orderFront:]`. There is a convenience method that is often used to do both: `[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:]`.

Comment: I have done this, but it still not worked, it will first flash to show the first window, then  show the second window.

Comment: The second window did be the top window on screen, but there was a flash to show the first window, And I print the windowOrdered it was {firstwindow, secondWindow} even though I ordered the secondWindow front. [/cry]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just know that I should click the check to mark the accepted answer.